# Malformed URL encoding in Spring request param

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, utf-8

I have a Spring controller, which accepts an encoded URL as a query parameter.

```
https://www.example.com/mysearch?_encoding=UTF8&searchUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2Fsearch%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2
```

My controller has a request mapping on `/mysearch`, an accepts a parameter:

```
@RequestMapping("/mysearch")
public ModelAndView doSearch(@RequestParam("searchUrl") final String url) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a malformed URL inside the controller:

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?a=1&amp;b=2
```

I have the CharacterEncodingFilter in my web.xml as the first filter already.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you obtaining your malformed URL? `&amp;` is the HTML `&` entity, are you displaying it inside your view? What gives you `System.out.println(url)`?

Comment: @kagmole System.out.println is printing the malformed URL with '&' encoded as '&amp;'